# Passport expires in less than 3 months when travelling from India to Ireland via France

Tags: passports, india, france, ireland

I'm resident in Ireland, my residence permit expires in 2023, however my Indian passport expires in January, 2022.

I'm travelling to India soon and was wondering if I'll have any issues flying back to Ireland via France due to my passport validity?

Comment: Not sure if that makes a difference, but can you clarify if both flights are on the same ticket or if there’s any reason for you to have to go through immigration in Paris (different tickets, different airports…)?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, get a new passport in India and travel back with that, simply because it is usually a bit easier to get a new passport while in your country of citizenship. Do take your residence permit with you.

Your residence permit should not be tied to a specific passport and be valid on its own. Having a valid residence permit, the expiry date of your passport should not be a problem, this is usually only problematic for short stay visits where you need to be able to show that you will be able to leave the country, but as you have residency, that should not concern you.

You need to ensure, however, that your residency in Ireland is not considered abandoned for staying out of the country too long, which . I doubt this would be the case if your travel is shorter than 3 months, to be sure, tell us the approximate travel dates

Comment: I'm only going to India for a week so might not have enough time to renew the passport but there's an Indian embassy in Ireland that does them so that'll be the first thing I do when I get back.